# Spring Boot service cannot be started

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm having trouble starting my Spring Boot application.

When I run it I get the following errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed 

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I work on Linux. Tomcat server is listening on port 8080 (can't change to another one). Other services work fine. Restarting the application or computer didn't help.

Comment: "embedded Tomcat" sounds not like "Tomcat listening"...please refer to ["traditional deployment"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a process running and listening on port 8080. You can check it with the command netstat.

If you can't change the port of your application then the only option would be to kill the other process. You can get the process number with this command:

```
netstat -nap | grep 8080
```